# C# - Countdown Timer Using NumericUpDown as Interval

Tags: c#, timer, countdown

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I cannot seem to find a solution that works.  I have a NumericUpDown on my form and a label along with a timer and a button.  I want the timer to start when the button is pressed and the interval for the timer to equal that of the NumericUpDown and a countdown will be displayed in the label.  I know this should be easy.  Any help?

So far:

```
   int tik = Convert.ToInt32(TimerInterval.Value);

    if (tik >= 0)
    {
        TimerCount.Text = (tik--).ToString();
    }

    else
    {
        TimerCount.Text = "Out of Time";
    }
```

It doesn't seem to update as the timer ticks.

Comment: whats your specific issue? people wont just write your code for you.

Comment: I write his code for him, as long as its not homework and he pays me

Comment: Not homework, personal project.  And I don't like the idea of people writing code for me, I'm just stuck.  I'll update the post to show what I have so far.

Comment: @Nate, you start the timer...and the interval of the timer indicates how often it ticks..but when does it stop ?! what are you counting down to? remember the interval is only how often you want the timer to execute something.

Comment: @Stan, sorry I've been up for about 30 hours straight, not thinking clearly.  Here's what I'm going for.  It's a screenshot program with a timer.  The user selects the number of seconds before the screenshot is taken by using the numericupdown control.  When the user presses the main button, the countdown timer starts to take the screenshot.  What I am trying to do, is display a countdown for the user to see that updates every second.  So for example, if the user selected to take a screenshot in 5 seconds, it would read "Capture in 5 seconds" followed by "Capture in 4 seconds" etc etc.

Comment: @Nate, that means your timer interval should be 1sec, every time it ticks you should change the label to the tick number youre on, until it reaches 0 then you execute your event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example to what you are looking for. This should give you a basic idea on what you need to do

```
    //class variable
    private int totNumOfSec;

    //set the event for the tick
    //and the interval each second
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 1000;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        totNumOfSec = (int)this.numericUpDown1.Value; 
        timer1.Start();
    }

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //check the timer tick
        totNumOfSec--;
        if (totNumOfSec == 0)
        {
            //do capture
            MessageBox.Show("Captured");
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else
            label1.Text = "Caputring in " + totNumOfSec.ToString();
    }
```